# python Superclass can call a function from its subclass?

Tags: python, class, sockets, object

I checked the **SocketServer.py** package.
Find the one function of class **BaseServer**--- **'_handle_request_noblock()**'
It has  :request, client_address = **self.get_request()**

But the function **get_request()** is built from **BaseServer's** ***subclass TCPServer and UDPServer*.**

How can I understand this?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch

Comment: This is one of the great powers of OOP, and should be explained in most tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On top of [Dynamic Dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch) as referred to by @JeremyFisher, such behavior is also related to the OOP concepts of [Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)) and [Polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)) (or [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/polymorphism-in-python/)) which in turn is related to [Liskov's Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). In Python, this behavior is visible in [MRO](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/).

Let's say we have this hierarchy of classes

```
>>> class BaseServer:
...     def handle_request_noblock(self):
...         print("BaseServer:handle_request_noblock")
...         self.get_request()
... 
>>> class TCPServer(BaseServer):
...     def get_request(self):
...         print("TCPServer:get_request")
... 
>>> 
>>> class UDPServer(BaseServer):
...     def get_request(self):
...         print("UDPServer:get_request")
... 
>>>
```

Let's see the attributes of the child class objects

```
>>> # base_server = BaseServer()  # This should not be done because "abstract" base classes are just blueprints, thus they are incomplete as in our example here where it has no definition of <get_request>. A derived "concrete" subclass is needed.
>>>
>>> tcp_server = TCPServer()
>>> udp_server = UDPServer()
>>>
>>> print(dir(tcp_server))
[...<trimmed for better viewing>..., 'get_request', 'handle_request_noblock']
>>> print(dir(udp_server))
[...<trimmed for better viewing>..., 'get_request', 'handle_request_noblock']
>>>
```

- As you can see, both subclasses has the `handle_request_noblock` attribute even if they don't explicitly define it, they just inherited it from the base class.

  > an object created through inheritance, a "child object", acquires all the properties and behaviors of the "parent object"
- Then, they have the `get_request` which they implemented on their own.

Let's call now the entrypoint function

```
>>> tcp_server.handle_request_noblock()
BaseServer:handle_request_noblock
TCPServer:get_request
>>> udp_server.handle_request_noblock()
BaseServer:handle_request_noblock
UDPServer:get_request
>>>
```

- As you can see, `BaseServer:handle_request_noblock` was able to call e.g. `TCPServer:get_request`. Why? Remember that the object we used is a `TCPServer` instance and based on the available methods we displayed on the earlier step, we saw that both `handle_request_noblock`  and `get_request` are available to it, so we know that both can be called. Same with `UDPServer`.

In Python, the technicalities of such dispatch from base to derived class is through [MRO](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/method-resolution-order-in-python-inheritance/).

> Python supports classes inheriting from other classes. The class being inherited is called the Parent or Superclass, while the class that inherits is called the Child or Subclass. In python, method resolution order defines the order in which the base classes are searched when executing a method. First, the method or attribute is searched within a class and then it follows the order we specified while inheriting.

```
>>> print(TCPServer.mro())
[<class '__main__.TCPServer'>, <class '__main__.BaseServer'>, <class 'object'>]
>>> print(UDPServer.mro())
[<class '__main__.UDPServer'>, <class '__main__.BaseServer'>, <class 'object'>]
>>>
```

- So for `TCPServer`

  - This means that when we called `handle_request_noblock`, it checked first if the implementation is present in `class TCPServer`, since it isn't, it checks to the next which is `class BaseServer`, since it is there, then it uses that implementation, so if you override it within `TCPServer`, it wouldn't have to call the implementation in the `BaseServer` anymore.
  - Then when we called `get_request`,  it checked first if the implementation is present in `class TCPServer`, since it is there, then it uses that implementation, no more need to check if it is present in `BaseServer`.
- Same idea with `UDPServer`.

Comment: Thank you for so much detail!